# Perform firestore collection group query in cloud functions with admin sdk?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

The firestore .collectionGroup() method is getting an error when using it with the firebase-admin sdk in a cloud function.  Is it possible to make a collection group query to firestore in a cloud function?

Here is the firestore query method I'm trying to use: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#collectionGroup

But it doesn't seem to be available in the firestore admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore

```
admin.firestore().collectionGroup('photos').where('id', '==', photoId);
```

I get this error when running the function:

> TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collectionGroup is not a function

Wondering if I'm missing something, or if this something that will be added in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This typically means you're using a version of the Admin SDK that doesn't support Collection Group Queries yet.

Support for Collection Group Queries was introduced in [version 7.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_740_-_may_21_2019), based on Cloud Firestore client 1.3.0. Check your package.json to ensure you're using these versions or newer.