# TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function - Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a data structure made this way:

- Posts(collection)
- UserId(document)
- Posts(collection)
- postDoc (document)

And I'm setting a cloud function to change all Posts(subcollection) documents upon a certain event, and in order to do so I'm using `collectionGroup` queries:

This is how I set it up:

```
exports.changeIsVisibleFieldAfterDay = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {
  const querySnapshot = db.collectionGroup("Posts")
      .where("isVisible", "==", true).get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
});
```

In the `Firebase Log` I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function
```

Searching [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915734/perform-firestore-collection-group-query-in-cloud-functions-with-admin-sdk/56915903?noredirect=1#comment116713598_56915903) I found out that there may be a problem with Firebase SDK version but mine is uptodate, I attach the `package.json` file here:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: How do you define `db`?

Comment: const db = admin.firestore(); @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `get()` method is **asynchronous**, so you either need to use `then()` to get the `querySnapshot` when the Promise returned by `get()` is fulfilled, or use `async/await`. More details on how to deal with asynchronous calls in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/3371862).

#### With `then()`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.changeIsVisibleFieldAfterDay = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {
  return db.collectionGroup("Posts").where("isVisible", "==", true).get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
     });
     return null;
  })
});
```

#### With `async/await`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.changeIsVisibleFieldAfterDay = functions.pubsub
.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
  const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup("Posts").where("isVisible", "==", true).get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data());
  });
  return null;
});
```

---

Note the `return null;` at the end. See this [doc item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on this key point.

---

Note also that if you want to update several docs within the `forEach()` loop, you will need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Many SO answers cover this case.

Comment: Perfect answer, I just have one more question regarding the little edit you made at the bottom, If I want to update several docs using then() statement do I still need to use Promise.all()?
And finally the ```then()``` option and ```async/await``` options are interchangeable, so I can freely use one of them for the other?

Comment: Yes you need to use `Promise.all()` if you want to execute several calls to an asynchronous method (like `update()`) in parallel. You can look at this search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3371862+Promise.all+cloud+function which lists several examples with Cloud Function. If you update your question with some updated code, I'll be able to look at it. `then()` option and `async/await` option are interchangeable but **you should not mix them**. If you think my answer helped you please upvote and accept it, thanks.

Comment: of course I upvoted it and accepted it, really helpful thank you!